# How Googlebot interprets my url

Tags: javascript, url, googlebot

I have a question about how the google crawler (googlebot) will do in this case:

> http://www.url.com?query=something#!somethingelse

Will this be changed to:

> http://www.url.com?query=something?_escaped_fragment_=somethingelse

or

> http://www.url.com?query=something&_escaped_fragment_=somethingelse

Will it continue the query parameters or will it break it by creating a new one using ?

Comment: Have you already read [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html)?

Comment: @Gumbo Yes I have. According to the documentation !# will be replaced with  "?_escaped_fragment_=" but it doesn't specify if it will be changed to "&_escaped_fragment_=" if there already is a parameter before the !#. Maybe I have missed something?

Comment: I guess it will either be prepended or appended to the existing query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crawler reads it as:
    http://www.url.com?query=something&_escaped_fragment_=somethingelse